# grep all lines from start of file to line containing a string

Tags: command-line, grep

If I have input file containing

```
statementes
asda
rertte 
something 
nothing here
```

I want to grep / extract (without using awk) every line from starting till I get the string "something". How can I do this? grep -B does not work since it needs the exact number of lines.

Desired output:

```
statementes
asda
rertte 
something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not completely robust, but sure -B works... just make the -B count huge:

```
grep -B `wc -l <filename>` -e 'something' <filename>
```

Comment: How do you pass a command output to a parameter, anyways? xargs? Even better than `wc -l` passed to `grep -B` would be to use `grep -n something | cut -d: -f1` and pass that to `head -n`

Comment: You are right. This is not robust at all. Spews out garbage in many cases.

Comment: @skype: help me out, what cases?

Comment: @armandino: closer, but output needs to be processed afterwards

Comment: @jmilloy:"grep -n something | cut -d: -f1 and pass that to head -n" works wonderfully. Thanks a lot.

Comment: nice, I added it separately because it seemed different enough, but i suppose there's no need. thanks to armandino for the needed backhash trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bash while loop and exit early when you hit the string:

```
$ cat file | while read line; do
> echo $line
> if echo $line | grep -q something; then
> exit 0
> fi
> done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
head -n `grep -n -e 'something' <filename> | cut -d: -f1` <filename>
```